# Make multiply rows into some column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have problem to converting rows into some columns using R. I give you the sample. i have table like this

```
datex <- c("01/01/21","02/01/21","03/01/21","04/01/21","05/01/21","06/01/21",
           "07/01/21","08/01/21","09/01/21","10/01/21","11/01/21","12/01/21",
           "13/01/21","14/01/21","15/01/21","16/01/21","17/01/21","18/01/21",
           "19/01/21","20/01/21","21/01/21","22/01/21","23/01/21","24/01/21",
           "25/01/21","26/01/21","27/01/21")
values <- c(24,34,11,1,0,11,15,18,0,11,15,18,21,5,5,23,44,32,12,3,4,7,5,4,10,6,6)
x <- data.frame(datex, variables, values)
```

and i want to convert this table into this table.

```
datex <- c("01/01/21","02/01/21","03/01/21","04/01/21","05/01/21","06/01/21",
           "07/01/21","08/01/21","09/01/21","10/01/21","11/01/21","12/01/21",
           "13/01/21","14/01/21","15/01/21","16/01/21","17/01/21","18/01/21",
           "19/01/21","20/01/21","21/01/21","22/01/21","23/01/21","24/01/21",
           "25/01/21","26/01/21","27/01/21")

values <- c(24,34,11,1,0,11,15,18,0,11,15,18,21,5,5,23,44,32,12,3,4,7,5,4,10,6,6)
y <- data.frame(datex, values)
```

Thank You

UPDATE:
This is real sample of data.

Comment: Please share reproducible example using dput(). A pic doesn't help.

Comment: Ok sir, i'll do it

Comment: i just add the R script, i hope you can help me sir. Thank You.

Comment: Have posed my answer, please check if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% separate_rows(variables) %>% 
   mutate(names = str_extract(variables, '[A-Z]+')) %>% 
   pivot_wider(id_cols = c(datex,value), names_from = names, values_from = variables)
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   datex      value A     B     C    
   <date>     <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 2021-01-01    80 A1    NA    NA   
 2 2021-01-02    38 A2    NA    NA   
 3 2021-01-03    88 A1    B1    NA   
 4 2021-01-04    72 A1    B1    C1   
 5 2021-01-05    56 A1    B1    C2   
 6 2021-01-06    91 A2    NA    C1   
 7 2021-01-07    61 NA    B1    NA   
 8 2021-01-08    81 NA    B2    NA   
 9 2021-01-09    44 NA    B2    C1   
10 2021-01-10    26 NA    B2    C2   
11 2021-01-11    26 NA    NA    C1   
12 2021-01-12    71 NA    NA    C2
```

Data used:

```
structure(list(datex = structure(c(18628, 18629, 18630, 18631, 
18632, 18633, 18634, 18635, 18636, 18637, 18638, 18639), class = "Date"), 
    variables = c("A1", "A2", "A1,B1", "A1,B1,C1", "A1,B1,C2", 
    "A2,C1", "B1", "B2", "B2,C1", "B2,C2", "C1", "C2"), value = c(80, 
    38, 88, 72, 56, 91, 61, 81, 44, 26, 26, 71)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Updated answer:

```
x %>% separate_rows(variables, sep = ',') %>% 
+   mutate(name = str_extract(variables, '.*(?=\\s=\\s.*)')) %>% 
+   pivot_wider(id_cols = c(datex,values), names_from = name, values_from = variables) %>% 
+   print(n = 50)
# A tibble: 27 x 6
   datex    values api               hostname            product_id     status_code    
   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>             <chr>               <chr>          <chr>          
 1 01/01/21     24 api = http://xxx/ NA                  NA             NA             
 2 02/01/21     34 api = http://xxx/ NA                  NA             NA             
 3 03/01/21     11 api = http://yyy/ NA                  NA             NA             
 4 04/01/21      1 api = http://yyy/ NA                  NA             NA             
 5 05/01/21      0 api = http://xxx/ hostname = digital1 NA             NA             
 6 06/01/21     11 api = http://xxx/ hostname = digital1 NA             NA             
 7 07/01/21     15 api = http://xxx/ hostname = digital2 NA             NA             
 8 08/01/21     18 api = http://xxx/ hostname = digital2 NA             NA             
 9 09/01/21      0 NA                hostname = digital1 NA             NA             
10 10/01/21     11 NA                hostname = digital1 NA             NA             
11 11/01/21     15 NA                hostname = digital2 NA             NA             
12 12/01/21     18 NA                hostname = digital2 NA             NA             
13 13/01/21     21 api = http://xxx/ hostname = digital1 product_id = 0 NA             
14 14/01/21      5 api = http://xxx/ hostname = digital1 product_id = 1 NA             
15 15/01/21      5 api = http://xxx/ hostname = digital2 product_id = 0 NA             
16 16/01/21     23 NA                NA                  product_id = 0 NA             
17 17/01/21     44 NA                NA                  product_id = 1 NA             
18 18/01/21     32 NA                NA                  product_id = 2 NA             
19 19/01/21     12 NA                hostname = digital1 product_id = 0 NA             
20 20/01/21      3 NA                hostname = digital1 product_id = 1 NA             
21 21/01/21      4 NA                hostname = digital1 product_id = 2 NA             
22 22/01/21      7 NA                NA                  NA             status_code = 1
23 23/01/21      5 NA                NA                  NA             status_code = 2
24 24/01/21      4 NA                NA                  NA             status_code = 3
25 25/01/21     10 api = http://xxx/ hostname = digital1 product_id = 0 status_code = 1
26 26/01/21      6 api = http://xxx/ hostname = digital1 product_id = 1 status_code = 1
27 27/01/21      6 api = http://xxx/ hostname = digital2 product_id = 0 status_code = 1
```

Comment: Sir, my data contains character like "A = A1" and "A = A1, B = B1". I want to separate them into column.

Comment: in real data, A, B & C are my API name. It's too long, so i use sample A,B & C. Thank You.

Comment: @CarolusMardisonPurba, have updated my answer, please check if that works.

Comment: sir, i use my data using my script to produce x, and running your script, but i get this result "no applicable method for 'separate_rows_' applied to an object of class "character"".

Comment: Sorry, i am newbie in R, and still learning about dplyr package.

Comment: @CarolusMardisonPurba,  It works for the data you provided, I can't visualize your actual data, if you can share actual data, a few rows, it would be possible to recreate and fix the error.

Comment: Ok sir, i'll do it in sample real data.

Comment: Sir, i just post sample of my real data. Hope you can help me. Thank You

Comment: sorry sir, it's typo from "Variabels" instead "Variables". I have corrected it

Comment: @CarolusMardisonPurba, what's your expected output?

Comment: my bad, i thought i have copy all. wait.

Comment: i have add what output that i want sir. Thank You

Comment: @CarolusMardisonPurba, have updated my answer, please check if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, finally i can sleep now. Many Thank You sir. I Appreciate it.

Comment: Hello sir, i am just running the script for all my data and unfortunately my data has many duplicate row and the result is not "chr", but "list". can help me again? thank you

Comment: @CarolusMardisonPurba, can you remove those duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a better solution

```
x %>% separate_rows(variables, sep = ",") %>% 
  separate(variables, into = c("var_name", "var"), sep = " = ") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var_name, values_from = var)

# A tibble: 12 x 5
   datex    value A     B     C    
   <chr>    <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 01/01/21    80 A1    NA    NA   
 2 02/01/21    38 A2    NA    NA   
 3 03/01/21    88 A1    B1    NA   
 4 04/01/21    72 A1    B1    C1   
 5 05/01/21    56 A1    B1    C2   
 6 06/01/21    91 A2    NA    C1   
 7 07/01/21    61 NA    B1    NA   
 8 08/01/21    81 NA    B2    NA   
 9 09/01/21    44 NA    B2    C1   
10 10/01/21    26 NA    B2    C2   
11 11/01/21    26 NA    NA    C1   
12 12/01/21    71 NA    NA    C2
```

Output with your second sample

```
x %>% separate_rows(variables, sep = ",") %>% 
  separate(variables, into = c("var_name", "var"), sep = " = ") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var_name, values_from = var)

# A tibble: 27 x 6
   datex    values api         hostname product_id status_code
   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>       <chr>    <chr>      <chr>      
 1 01/01/21     24 http://xxx/ NA       NA         NA         
 2 02/01/21     34 http://xxx/ NA       NA         NA         
 3 03/01/21     11 http://yyy/ NA       NA         NA         
 4 04/01/21      1 http://yyy/ NA       NA         NA         
 5 05/01/21      0 http://xxx/ digital1 NA         NA         
 6 06/01/21     11 http://xxx/ digital1 NA         NA         
 7 07/01/21     15 http://xxx/ digital2 NA         NA         
 8 08/01/21     18 http://xxx/ digital2 NA         NA         
 9 09/01/21      0 NA          digital1 NA         NA         
10 10/01/21     11 NA          digital1 NA         NA         
# ... with 17 more rows
```

full output

```
      datex values         api hostname product_id status_code
1  01/01/21     24 http://xxx/     <NA>       <NA>        <NA>
2  02/01/21     34 http://xxx/     <NA>       <NA>        <NA>
3  03/01/21     11 http://yyy/     <NA>       <NA>        <NA>
4  04/01/21      1 http://yyy/     <NA>       <NA>        <NA>
5  05/01/21      0 http://xxx/ digital1       <NA>        <NA>
6  06/01/21     11 http://xxx/ digital1       <NA>        <NA>
7  07/01/21     15 http://xxx/ digital2       <NA>        <NA>
8  08/01/21     18 http://xxx/ digital2       <NA>        <NA>
9  09/01/21      0        <NA> digital1       <NA>        <NA>
10 10/01/21     11        <NA> digital1       <NA>        <NA>
11 11/01/21     15        <NA> digital2       <NA>        <NA>
12 12/01/21     18        <NA> digital2       <NA>        <NA>
13 13/01/21     21 http://xxx/ digital1          0        <NA>
14 14/01/21      5 http://xxx/ digital1          1        <NA>
15 15/01/21      5 http://xxx/ digital2          0        <NA>
16 16/01/21     23        <NA>     <NA>          0        <NA>
17 17/01/21     44        <NA>     <NA>          1        <NA>
18 18/01/21     32        <NA>     <NA>          2        <NA>
19 19/01/21     12        <NA> digital1          0        <NA>
20 20/01/21      3        <NA> digital1          1        <NA>
21 21/01/21      4        <NA> digital1          2        <NA>
22 22/01/21      7        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>           1
23 23/01/21      5        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>           2
24 24/01/21      4        <NA>     <NA>       <NA>           3
25 25/01/21     10 http://xxx/ digital1          0           1
26 26/01/21      6 http://xxx/ digital1          1           1
27 27/01/21      6 http://xxx/ digital2          0           1
```

Comment: Hi sir, in my second example, i got error like this "Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `A = A1`, `A = A2`, `A = A1, B = B1`, `A = A1, B = B1, C = C1`, `A = A1, B = B1, C = C2`, etc. don't exist."

Comment: oh my bad. i got this error "Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `api = http://xxx/`, `api = http://xxx/`, `api = http://yyy/`, `api = http://yyy/`, `api = http://xxx/,hostname = digital1`, etc. don't exist."